# Spring JPA + H2 DB : Save field value case insensitive

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, h2

I am writing a Spring Boot application using Spring JPA and H2 DB. In an entity `user`, I want to save the field `userId` with *unique* values in case **insensitive** manner.

So once the user inserts `userId` as *user1*, he must not be allowed to save another `userId` as *User1*.

One possible way is to make the `user` entity's *getters* read value in *lower/upper case* and the *setters* write the value in *lower/upper case*, as below :

```
public String getUserId() {
        return userId.toLowerCase();
}

public void setUserId(String userId) {
        this.userId = userId.toLowerCase();
}
```

Is there an alternate/better solution, preferably at schema level?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [H2 table columns doesn't respect case when double-quoted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38351676/h2-table-columns-doesnt-respect-case-when-double-quoted)

Comment: @Lemmy : Unfortunately not. It addresses for column name, and I am concerned for column value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how to configure it with annotations, but if you create your schema manually and can control the script you can use [varchar_ignorecase](https://www.h2database.com/html/datatypes.html#varchar_ignorecase_type) for the column. Then you can store your data in mixed case, but any database constraints you create and indeed any comparisons will ignore case.